# Resolution for require('module/subpath')

Tags: node.js, import, require, node-modules

How does node resolve `require('my-module/subpath')` and `import * from 'my-module/subpath'`?

Will this always resolve to either `subpath.js` or `subpath/index.js` inside my-module, or would it ever look elsewhere?

Is it possible to configure `my-module` so that `require('my-module/subpath')` or `import * from 'my-module/subpath'` resolves to `lib\subpath\index.js`?

Answer (score 1):

> How does node resolve require('my-module/subpath') and import * from 'my-module/subpath'?

Whether using `require` or `import`, `my-module/subpath` will resolve to `node_modules/my-module/subpath`

There it will search for:

1. `subpath.js`
2. `package.json` and its `main` field (for commonjs) or `module` (for esm).
3. `index.js`.

For comprehensive (albeit long) guide see `node resolution` section in the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-nodejs-resolves-modules).

**Note:** Most packages are not distributed in `my-module/subpath` format, but use `main` or `module` in `package.json` instead. One exception is [Material-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) which does so for esm exports (see [guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/)).

> Is it possible to configure my-module so that require('my-module/subpath') or import * from 'my-module/subpath' resolves to lib\subpath\index.js?

Virtually all related tools provide a way to alter module resolution via aliases. How you achieve that depends on which tool you use:

- babel (via `babel-plugin-module-resolver`)
- webpack (via the `resolve.alias` property)
- typescript/VSCode (where it's called `paths` in `tsconfig` )
- eslint (via `eslint-plugin-import`

etc.